# Fabric script output with execute

Tags: python, linux, devops, fabric, system-administration

When I run this script.

```
from fabric.api import run, roles

env.roledefs = {
    'db': ['db1', 'db2'],
    'web': ['web1', 'web2', 'web3'],
}

@roles('db')
def migrate():
    # Database stuff here.
    pass

@roles('web')
def update():
    # Code updates here.
    pass

def deploy():
    execute(migrate)
    execute(update
```

I don't get any feed back in the terminal about the individual functions that have, only this.
`[me@localhost Scripts]$ fab fabfile.py deploy
 Parallel tasks now using pool size of 2 
 [HostName1] Executing task 'migrate'
 [HostName2] Executing task 'update'`

Why can't I get the same information as when I run the functions indiviually. Even if I use this in the functions.

```
with show('debug'), settings(warn_only=True):
```

I'd be interested to know why or if it is possible to get more output.

Comment: have you tried `fab --echo` ?

Comment: fab --echo doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried --show=everything. I am using fabric2.4. Check this url http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/output_controls.html#output-level-aliases